# Advice on preparing/presenting a Python Master Class?

Tags: python, computer-science

I am preparing a master class to present to a group of Technical Artists# at work. Everyone in the group has previously programmed in C/C++/MEL/MAXScript/Python. The purpose of the class is to collectively bring everyone's skill levels and technical understanding on variety of Computer Science topics to a common level.

I would like some advice as this first time I've delivered such a class.

I am planning on structuring the course to be two 2 hour sessions, with 30 minute blocks of content interspersed with Q&A, code-review, and individual assistance.

I know this a multi-part question, so don't feel you need to be able answer everything, just contribute what you can. **Any links to articles, SO questions, or reflection on personal learning experiences is greatly appreciated.**

**Questions/Advice/Links to Further Reading**
 - What CS topics should I attempt to cover?
 - Examples of other Python training courses? 
 - What do you wish someone taught you when you first started programming?
 - Python programming best-practices
 - Tips for delivering technical content to creative/artist audience?

Using Dive Into Python as a textbook and referencing the MIT OpenCourseware [Introduction to Computer Science](http://academicearth.org/lectures/intro-to-comp-sci-goals) on [Academic Earth](http://academicearth.org/). I have also been given a 2 minute overview on adult training (Malcolm Knowles), i.e., working the students through the cycle of: identify the problem, determine the cause, researching a solution, and applying.

*# Technical Artists: write tools, create/script rigs, and manages the creation of data in DCC packages (Adobe Photoshop, Autodesk Maya and 3ds Max).*

Comment: I can provide more details if required. Just let me know...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just some quick comments/thoughts from my experience:

- I think your time allotment is tight, so I would focus on a handful of key topics to drive home.  Certainly spend some time on basic lists, tuple and dictionary usage and manipulation.
- I like to put together a cheat sheet of libraries and select methods/examples for the students so they get a sense of the "python universe" and how much is available.
- "Dive into Python" is decent book, but I think you can find more succinct and effective tutorials online, or more complete references (Learning Python, by Lutz?).
- Pick good example problems to illustrate points, and personalize them if possible.  Have little "extra credit" teasers available for ambitious students.
- Make sure you gauge your audience's preparedness well, and especially consider the spread in their abilities.

Is this a class to prepare them with python skills for specific tasks, or an introduction to python (where they will learn more on their own later)?

Comment: Thank-you for your answer. Time allocation is unfortunately tight, I am hopeful that after the feedback from these initial sessions I will be able to get more time approved by HR. The first sessions will be an introduction to Python, with games-related examples demonstrated in Maya.